# How to only replace all hyphens after 2nd instance

Tags: c#, indexof

In a string like this: Last-Name — lives on a road, in south-shore.
I am trying to replace all instances of "," & "-" in to " " with only skipping the 2nd instance of "-". I then want to replace the "-" with a ",". 
I have currently tried to us this:

```
var all = node.InnerText.Replace(","," ");
var hyph = all.Replace("—",",").Replace("-",",");
```

Which works... except it is replacing everything and I am needing the 2nd instance of "—" to remain while all other instances of ",", "—" & "-"'s are changed to " ". So it looks like this when it is done: 
(Last, Name , lives on a road in south, shore.). 
When I need it to look like: (Last Name , lives on a road in south shore).

Doing some looking around, it seems that IndexOf() is the way to go but I am unsure of how to setup my query. Would I be on the right track using something like this? Or is there a better way to go about this? To be honest I am not entirely sure and I am still learning C# so sorry if this is poorly worded or way off mark.

```
int position = dash.IndexOf(find);
if (position > 1)
{
return dash;
}
return dash.Substring(1, position) + replace + dash.Substring(postion + find.Length);
```

In every case it will be:

last name — some text here

*or*

last name — some-sort of text

*or*

last-name — more text, here

*or*

last name — more-text here

Where it just needs to be:

last name, some text here.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you give some more examples of what is, and what needs to be?

Comment: In every case it will be last name — some text here OR last name — some-sort of text OR last-name — more text, here OR last name — more-text here. Where it just needs to be last name, some text here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
int firstHyph = all.IndexOf('-'); // find the first hyphen
int secondHyph = all.IndexOf('-', firstHyph + 1); // find the second hyphen
var sb = new StringBuilder(all);
sb[secondHyph] = '#'; // replace the second hyphen with some improbable character
// finally, replace all hyphen and whatever you need and change that 
// "second hyphen" (now sharp) to whatever you want
var result = sb.ToString().Replace("-", " ").Replace("#", ",");
```

Comment: Sorry, this does work as intended. Thank you. Due to the complex nature and my lack of further explanation, it wont be a working solution to my problem... But this is not of fault to your code but the fault of poor HTML formatting. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Do this with regex, look up for search operator and set it to search for everything after the first. Sorry answering this on the phone so I can't look it up at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and, exclusive solution

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string all = Convert.ToString("In every case it will be last name — some text here OR last name — some-sort of text OR last-name — more text, here OR last name — more-text here").Replace(",", " ");
        int hyph1 = all.IndexOf('—');
        int hyph2 = hyph1 + all.Substring(++hyph1).IndexOf('—');
        string partial = all.Substring(0, ++hyph2).Replace("—", " ");
        string res = String.Concat(partial, "—", all.Substring(++hyph2).Replace("—", " ").Replace("-", ","));
        Console.Write(res.ToString());
    }
}
```

See on the Fiddle:

http://ideone.com/wWCGeA